# Using Bootstrap Icons in Rails 6 with Webpacker

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, webpacker

I wanted to use Bootstrap icons in beta "Official open source SVG icon library for Bootstrap." https://icons.getbootstrap.com/. This is for Bootstrap 4 in Rails 6.

I tried various imports and includes in application.js and application.scss with no success

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 24):

You can also use it via CSS, which I find convenient and familiar to the glyph icon support of old.  First, add bootstrap-icons:

```
yarn add bootstrap-icons
```

Then, simply import it in your `application.js` file:

```
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css'
```

Finally, wherever you want to use it, just use an `<i>` tag:

```
<i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i>
```

That should be it!

Comment: Works for me. Rails 6.1.4.

Answer (score 12):

I found the basis of  the solution on this GitHub [discussion](https://github.com/twbs/icons/issues/79) with @chriskrams supplying the key information.

I ran `yarn add bootstrap-icons` to install the icons.

I then created a helper in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`. The empty `module ApplicationHelper` had been created automagically.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def icon(icon, options = {})
    file = File.read("node_modules/bootstrap-icons/icons/#{icon}.svg")
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse file
    svg = doc.at_css 'svg'
    if options[:class].present?
      svg['class'] += " " + options[:class]
    end
      doc.to_html.html_safe
  end
end
```

`node_modules/bootstrap-icons/icons/` is where yarn installs the icons.

To use the icons `<%= icon("bicycle", class: "text-success") %>` for example.

You can also see available icons in `app/node_modules/bootstrap-icons/icons/`

Comment: Should I move the answer to a comment or is leaving it in the revised post OK? I've seen revised posts. Thank you

Comment: Modified this slightly... file = File.read("#{Rails.root}/node_modules/bootstrap-icons/icons/#{icon}.svg") AND "alert-circle" isn't an icon, so for testing purposes anyone reading this may want to change that.

Comment: This solution will read each the time web page is render. This is a performance penalty.

Comment: How to avoid that? For my app it doesn't matter, but not best practice.

Answer (score 10):

You need to override the default font definition to load the appropriate paths

```
yarn add bootstrap-icons
```

Then add to your `application.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons";
@font-face {
  font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
  src: font-url("bootstrap-icons/font/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2") format("woff2"),
    font-url("bootstrap-icons/font/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff") format("woff");
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
<i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i>
```

Make sure you have `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')` in your `config/initializers/assets.rb`

Comment: `application.scss:7 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2?856008caa5eb66df68595e734e59580d'`

Comment: `./fonts/`? It is supposed to start with `bootstrap-icons/font`. Double check my answer, I fixed some paths after I first posted it.

Comment: I copied your application.scss today and `bootstrap-icons/font/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2` exists in my `node-modules`.  My fix still works, but I thought I'd try yours, but my set up must be a bit different. I reran `yarn add bootstrap-icons` and it had updated.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Followed your instructions to the T. 
`ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff?856008caa5eb66df68595e734e59580d' in '/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/app/javascript/packs'`

Comment: It's weird that your path says `./`, it is not supposed to be a relative path. Make sure that path is correct and that `node_modules` is in your `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`

Comment: This solution worked for me locally and on Heroku. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

installation:

```
yarn add bootstrap-icons
```

just require into src/app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require('bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css');
```

Comment: after having the same issues with the solutions above, this idea worked for me.  I ended up adding `import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css"` to `application.js`

Answer (score 3):

```
yarn add bootstrap-icons
```

Add the library first and then,

```
//= link_directory ../../../node_modules/bootstrap-icons .svg
```

add this line (to `app/assets/config/manifest.js` file) to use `bootstrap-icons.svg` file as follows (if for 'shop' icon)

```
<svg class="bi" fill="currentColor">
  <use xlink:href="<%= asset_path "bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg" %>#shop"/>
</svg>
```

Like "sprite" on this page. https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#usage In this way you can size / change color in simpler way.

UPDATE:

In addition, we can write up a helper in this case.

```
<%= bi_icon 'shop', class: 'shop-style' %>
```

```css
.shop-style {
  width: 16px; height: 16px; color: red;
}
```

For above, we can have something like:

```rb
  def bi_icon(icon, options = {})
    klasses = ["bi"].append(options.delete(:class)).compact
    content_tag :svg, options.merge(class: klasses, fill: "currentColor") do
      content_tag :use, nil, "xlink:href" => "#{ asset_path 'bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg' }##{icon}"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using rails 6.1.5 and tailwind.

Installed using `yarn add bootstrap-icons`

then added `import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css'` in `application.js`

Was able to add the icons using the `<i>` tag but somehow it shows 0 width or no stroke so I did added the following to `scaffolds.scss`

```css
    @import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons"; 
    @font-face {   
            font-family: "bootstrap-icons";   
            src: font-url("bootstrap-icons/font/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2") format("woff2"),
            font-url("bootstrap-icons/font/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff") format("woff"); }
```

Now the icons are properly displayed.